# How to call an activity instead of a fragment in Tablayout?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I have an android app in which I have 3 tabs in a tablayout. I simply want the first tab to open a new activity and not a fragment, because I'll have new tabs in this new activity. What's the best solution for that?

I have tried to desing with a linear layout a "fake tab" but the problem is it's never gonna have the same size as the other tabs.

Is there a way to do that like this?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

    adapter = new TabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new ProfileActivity(), "Profile");
    adapter.addFragment(new SwipeFragment(), "Meet");
    adapter.addFragment(new FriendsFragment(), "Friends");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
}
```

this addFragment method does not accept an Activity so that line is in error. Someone has any idea on how can I achieve this?
Anyway in which I can make a tab call an activity instead of a fragment

Comment: did you find anything?